Is it possible to have a big difference between the ratio of primary-secondary voltage and the ratio of secondary-primary current?
I have a HF transformer that is expected to work at 1 kHz with voltage ratio Vp:Vs = 25:1. But when I put the pure resistance load at the secondary winding, the ratio of current Ip:Is = 1:6.67, which is too far from voltage ratio. Considering the T-model of the transformer, does it mean that the current for magnetizing and core loss is very high, compared to the effective current that produces the EMF in the secondary ? Thank you for your insight

Not enough information provided to be conclusive - could be core losses, poor coupling, or resistive losses. At minimum, you need to provide both the current and the voltage of the input and output. Further, more information is needed on the construction of the transformer (wire type, winding count, core geometry and composition, ect.). Or the part number or datasheet. Also, is 1kHz pure sine? Or square? Or other?

There are some possibilities to eliminate, but yes, that is one of them.

Yes it is possible. If secondary load is too large, the voltage will collapse. Conversely, without load there will be no secondary current.

The current ratio seems to be from measurement. Please report/assert same for voltage.

What’s the primary and secondary coil resistance? What’s your load?

If you look for the classical transformer model you might find something like the picture below:

You will also note that there will be a sort of variety. For instance, \$L_s\$ and \$R_s\$ can be transferred to the primary side (or vice-versa) and the magnetization branch (\$L_m\$ and \$R_m\$) can also be placed elsewhere. Another typical simplification is to unite the series elements of primary and secondary. But the main idea will not change too much.
When there is no load, there will be no voltage drop in the series elements and the voltage ratio will be the same as the turn ratio (\$n1/n2\$).
However, since you add some load to the secondary, the load current will flow through the windings and cause some voltage drop. Physically, these series elements the following:

\$L_p\$, \$L_s\$: represents the voltage drop due to the leakage flux between primary and secondary. In practice, when the transformer is loaded, not all the magnetic flux due to the load current will concatenate between primary and secondary. It is quantified in the 'impedance' value of that transformer.

\$R_p\$, \$R_s\$: stands for the transformer losses. It can be simplified as the ohmic resistance, but in practice it will also be bigger than the ohmic resistance because the transformer present losses other than \$RI^2\$.


So, you may expect some voltage drop that increases linearly with your load current. The Power Factor of your load will also influence this behavior.


voltage ratio Vp:Vs = 25:1. But ...the ratio of current Ip:Is = 1:6.67, which is too far from voltage ratio.

This can happen if the load current is very light compared to the rated load current of the transformer.
For example, consider a 120V to 4.8V, 60 Hz, 1000 VA transformer. The voltage ratio is 120/4.8 = 25, as in your example. At 120 V, the maximum primary current permitted would be 1000/120 = 8.3 A. A "good" transformer might have 1% of that as magnetizing current, or 830 mA. (At another extreme would be microwave oven transformers, which might draw 25% of their max current as magnetizing current. We will address them separately). The primary inductance to get 830 mA would be
$$L = \frac{V}{2\pi fI} = \frac{120}{2\pi \times 60 \times 0.833}= 382 mH$$
With a little algebra, I came up with a load resistance value of 836 m\$\Omega\$ as a secondary load that might give a ratio between primary and secondary currents of 1:6.67. Testing with the following circuit gave a primary current of 851 mA rms, and an rms secondary current of 5.74 A, which is a ratio of 6.75:1. Close enough.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note that the transformer was rated at 1000 VA, but the load on the secondary only draws 4.8 V x 5.74 A = 27.6 W.
As mentioned microwave oven transformers are at the other extreme for no-load primary current. Microwave oven transformers typically have a magnetic shunt inserted into the core to provide a certain amount of load regulation. As a result, a 1000 W microwave oven transformer might easily draw 2.5 A under no load.
So, there are at least two common ways that a 25:1 transformer might have a 1:6.67 current ratio.

The transformer may have large capacity relative to the current it is being tested with.
The transformer may intentionally have a shunt to provide some load regulation.

One way to test whether the issue is magnetization current, is to test the primary current at two different loads, and measure how the primary current changes in relation to how the secondary current changes. You may get much closer to a 25:1 ratio with such a test. (It shouldn't be exact because the magnetizing current is approximately 90 degrees out of phase from the primary current "induced" by the secondary current".)

does it mean that the current for magnetizing and core loss is very high, compared to the effective current that produces the EMF in the secondary ?

The magnetizing current is the current that produces the EMF in the secondary. They are the same thing. Perhaps you meant the current in the primary that results from the current in the secondary. In any event, yes, if the ratio of the magnetizing current plus core loss current to the primary current resulting from the secondary current is too large, the ratio between primary current and secondary current will be significantly lower than the turns ratio of the transformer.
